# How to configure Nginx with public IP?

Tags: 16.04, server, dns, nginx

When I execute curl http://localhost:80 I get an HTML page printed to the terminal with title of "Welcome to nginx!" which means that Nginx is working fine.
I have configured my Nginx as follow:

```
upstream appName {
    # Nodejs app upstream
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    keepalive 64;
}

# Server on port 80
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name Domain.online;
    root /home/user/appName;

    location / {
        # Proxy_pass configuration
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_pass http://appName/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }
}
```

When I ping my domain, I can see that it is pointed to my public IP successfully. But when I try to ping my public IP it shows me "unknown host".
I edited `/etc/hosts` and added `myPublicIP myDomainName` but it doesn't work.

How can I configure my public IP address with Nginx?

Comment: is your public IP address on a router or firewall which sits in front of your server, or is it assigned directly to the computer that you have NGINX set up on?

Comment: @ThomasWard not in the router. I am connecting through Lan and it is assigned new one every time I connect

Comment: are you getting an IP address that is actually public, or are you getting an IP address in one of the following ranges: 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.255.255, 172.16.0.1 - 172.31.255.255, 10.0.0.1 - 10.255.255.255 ?

Comment: @ThomasWard It is public IP starts with 94.185.x.x

Comment: Are you entering `Domain.online` or the IP address for your `ping` command?  Are you trying to ping locally or from a system that is *not* the system running the server?

Comment: @ThomasWard yes I tried to enter domain.online it doesn't show anything. I tried to ping locally, nothing happens till I press Ctrl + C. and when I try to ping from different PC, it shows me request timed out